Getting really strange data from a HOOMD blue model
When I run this code (I've tried different final densities, different spacing, and different numbers of particles) I end up getting pressure that fluctuates randomly in a completely nonsensical way, back and forth between values 16 orders of magnitude apart. Any idea why? It used to work, and I'm really not sure what I changed about it to make it start behaving so strangely.
import matplotlib

%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib_inline

import itertools
import math
import gsd.hoomd
import numpy
import datetime #import all libraries

matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats('svg') #plots will export as a SVG file


m = 15
N_particles = 4*m**3 #sets the number of particles in the simulation
spacing = 1.08 #the space between each particle
K = math.ceil(N_particles ** (1 / 3)) 
L = K * spacing #defines the length of the box
x = numpy.linspace(-L / 2, L / 2, K, endpoint=False) #sets K spaces from -L/2 to L/2
position = list(itertools.product(x, repeat=3)) #fill the entire box

frame = gsd.hoomd.Frame()
frame.particles.N = N_particles
frame.particles.position = position[0:N_particles] #randomly places each particle
frame.particles.typeid = [0] * N_particles
frame.configuration.box = [L, L, L, 0, 0, 0] #the box in which the particles could be placed

with gsd.hoomd.open(name='lattice.gsd', mode='x') as f:
    f.append(frame)
cpu = hoomd.device.CPU() 
simulation = hoomd.Simulation(device=cpu, seed=1)
simulation.create_state_from_gsd(
    filename='lattice.gsd'
) #define where the simulation runs

integrator = hoomd.md.Integrator(dt=0.05) #timestep length
cell = hoomd.md.nlist.Cell(buffer=0.4)
lj = hoomd.md.pair.LJ(nlist=cell) #use LJ molecular modeling pattern
lj.params[('A', 'A')] = dict(epsilon=1, sigma=1)
lj.r_cut[('A', 'A')] = 2.5
integrator.forces.append(lj)
simulation.state.thermalize_particle_momenta(filter=hoomd.filter.All(), kT=1.1) #temperature of particles
nvt = hoomd.md.methods.ConstantVolume( 
    filter=hoomd.filter.All(),
    thermostat=hoomd.md.methods.thermostats.Bussi(kT=1.1) #NVT, set thermostat
)
integrator.methods.append(nvt)

simulation.operations.integrator = integrator

thermodynamic_properties = hoomd.md.compute.ThermodynamicQuantities(
    filter=hoomd.filter.All()) #how many particles are we measuring
simulation.operations.computes.append(thermodynamic_properties)

logger = hoomd.logging.Logger(categories=['scalar'])
logger.add(simulation, quantities=['timestep'])
logger.add(thermodynamic_properties, quantities=['pressure'])
logger.add(thermodynamic_properties, quantities=['volume'])
logger.add(thermodynamic_properties, quantities=['num_particles'])
file = open('log.txt', mode='x', newline='\n')
table_file = hoomd.write.Table(
    output=file, trigger=hoomd.trigger.Periodic(period=200), logger=logger
)

simulation.operations.writers.append(table_file) #logging

simulation.run(1000)

ramp = hoomd.variant.Ramp(A=0, B=1, t_start=simulation.timestep, t_ramp=8000) #number of timesteps to run the ramp
rho = simulation.state.N_particles / simulation.state.box.volume #measure density
print(rho)
initial_box = simulation.state.box
final_box = hoomd.Box.from_box(initial_box)  #make a copy of initial_box
final_rho = 0.3 #final rho after all resizing
final_box.volume = simulation.state.N_particles / final_rho #do not change
box_resize_trigger = hoomd.trigger.Periodic(50) #how often is the box resized
box_resize = hoomd.update.BoxResize(
    box1=initial_box, box2=final_box, variant=ramp, trigger=box_resize_trigger
)
simulation.operations.updaters.append(box_resize)

simulation.run(10000) #run

```print("All done!!!")```

